# Query Tables Excel debugging Import

Tags: excel, import, vba

I used a macro to import data from a htm file. So far that querytables also worked very fine. I then moved the whole file to a online folder and it doesnt work anymore. The macro stops at the last line, backgroundquery. I think it kind of is related to the movement of the file to the online folder that the speed might not be fast enough to import the data. But i am not experienced enough to understand what is written there. I just recorded the macro. Do you know why it stopped working?

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;file:///C:/.../.../..." & Datei & ".htm",     Destination:= _
    Range("$A$1"))
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

It stops because it cannot load (.refresh) the file. Have you checked the path of the file?

Otherwise the problem can occure because you already have a querytable and it cannot create/replace the old querytable. Delete the old querytable and run your code again. To refresh an existing querytable use this sub:

```
Sub Refresh()
Dim qt As QueryTable
Set qt = Worksheets("Table1").ListObjects(1).QueryTable

With qt
   .Refresh
End With
End Sub
```